# User-based access control in ASP .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

What I'm trying to prevent is:

A: /SaveBook?bookId=12&title=Abc

B (Malicious user): /SaveBook?bookId=12&title=Def

I could check in every single one of my Actions to see if book 12 was created by user A, but that would be dangerous and tedious.

Maybe I don't know the right terminology, but I've found documents on Role-Based Access Control (RBAC), Permission-Based Access Control(PBAC), I even looked into Row-Level Security (RLS) in SQL Server, but I don't think that quite fits what I'm trying to do.  If it does, please tell me.  I would like a solution here that is rigorously tested in .Net and will receive the appropriate security updates that Microsoft provides when an issue is found.

I am using EF in Core 7.

Comment: *but that would be dangerous and tedious* but that's what row level security is implemented at the application layer: upon collecting arguments, you first check if user is authorized, whatever *authorized* means (e.g checking if record was created by currently authenticated user). It's not dangerous, possibly tedious but just necessary.

Comment: If you don't want to expose your request query string you can achieve that using post request so that user cannot see the request query string or even can use token.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, what?  That is not correct.  That's not what I'm trying to do, but you can absolutely see everything sent in a POST request.  Not to mention you can see the actual JavaScript crafting the POST.  Please tell me you're not using POST for security.  If you actually telnet into a web server and create a POST and GET request, you'll see they're not very different.

Comment: Have you tired any encryption before?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, if the client is encrypting the transmission, the client knows what the transmission is.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, have you ever heard of DevTools?

Comment: Is it browser extention isn't?

Comment: I'd suggest going for PBAC. You could encode current user permissions within a JWT upon signing in (or cache them) and then check if user has right permission before every action, whether in framework-provider manner or in a custom action filter applied on methods or controllers or even globally. I fail to see anything dangerous or tedious about that.

Comment: I'm trying to clarify your need, how do you authenticate the user? What type of authentication have you setup in .net. Next step is authorization you will have user that can call the get API and user that can call the post API, you can setup that level of access using policy. The next level which is more complicated is authorization control at object level the user can edit only the books that he created.